# Migrated project to Maven, where to put config folder

Tags: java, maven, config

I migrated my javafx recently to maven. It starts and works fine, but i cannot figure out where to place the config folder and how to say maven that it shell include it.

Before i converted the project to maven, the structure looked like this:

> |-src
>       |-lib
>       |-config

Now the sructure looks like this:

> |-src/main/java/my.super.program
>       |-src/main/resources/my.super.program
>       |-lib
>       |-config

I tried it with

> ```
>  <resource>         
>     <directory>config</directory>
>     <includes>
>       <include>*.xml</include>
>     </includes>
>   </resource>
> ```

but that hasn't worked.

In the main.java i declare the needed config files. For example:

> private final String configPath = 'config/config.xml';
>        private final String accountPath = 'config/account.xml';

How can I include the config folder and tell maven to use it?

Comment: How are you using `configPath` after that?

Comment: Did you consider `src\main\resources\config` ?

Comment: Tunaki: I use configPath to load (and save) the config with properties.

vikingsteve: see the comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default everything that is placed inside the src/main/resources is added to the jar file that is built. Alternatively you can create your own maven module holding the configuration. Again you will have to place it under src/main/resources

If you decide to create a dedicated module holding the configuration you will have to add it to the dependencies of the previous module. Preferably it will be a compile time dependence(this is the scope).

Comment: I copied the folder to src/main/resources. The folder with the content is now created under target/classes/ and contains the config.xml. But when i run jfx:run nothing will be copied to target/jfx/app/ .

Comment: You need to build the jar. Nothing is supposed to be under the target/jfx/app/   It is supposed to be top level inside your jar file. And then you are starting the jar.

Comment: Is their a way that the config folder will be copied automatically to target/jfx/app/ ? That would be nice, because if I run jfx:native the config folder is missing, but is needed for startup.

Comment: If you run  jfx:native from target/classes instead of just "target" It should work.

Answer (score -2):

I hope this answer doesn't confuse you, if it does, probably just seek a simpler solution.

---

Jars are not a good place for storing mutable configuration.  You can only put a default configuration in the jar file.  A jar file is not writable, so your program can't overwrite the configuration to update it if it is in the jar.

For apps that require user specific configuration, I'd be inclined to store the config in a `$USER_HOME/.myapp` directory.  An advantage of using the file system for configuration rather than a database or the java preferences API, is that the config can be easily viewed and edited using a standard text editor.

Sample code to determine a home directory for your application's config:

```
String configHome = System.getProperty("myapp.home", 
    System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.myapp"
);
```

You could access the resources for the default configuration out of the jar file and copy them to files on the file system.  Then a user could manually edit the files on the file system to configure your application.  Or, you could provide a custom UI that you create for the user to modify the info in the files.

An example of this approach is in this [OsiamHome](https://github.com/osiam/osiam/blob/master/src/main/java/org/osiam/OsiamHome.java) class, which is one of the nicest ways I have seen to setup configuration for a Java application (that's a server app, but the general principle could be used for a client application).  The osiam reference is a  [Spring](https://spring.io) application so that it benefits from some of the configuration support provided by Spring, in particular the [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html), that helps to recursively search a jar to find all default configuration resources for the application.

However, you probably don't need the additional facilities provided by the Spring based approach.  Instead, you can just keep a list in code of all the files in your default configuration and place the files in a `/resources/config` directory in your source tree.  The build process will copy the default configuration into your jar file for deployment.  When the application is run, if the config directory on the filesystem does not exist, the application can read the default config resources from your jar file and copy the config resources to files on the filesystem.  The config files can then be modified and changed as much as necessary.

Some other options you have for managing the configuration outside of your application jar are to:

1. Place the configuration information in a database OR
2. Use the [Java preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html) OR
3. Use a packaging system, e.g., [rpm](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/) or (perhaps) the [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html) tool or [javafx maven plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) which bundles the default configuration into a native deployment package.  Native OS deployment software can extract the configuration and copy it to a location you specify.  Usually, this location will be a standard configuration location for the OS, such as `/etc/myapp` on Linux for system wide config or `$USER_HOME/.myapp` for user specific config.

Comment: I am down voting you because you are not answering the question but turning it into a different question. His question is where to put configuration in maven project and not "what are the blueprints of configuration".

Comment: Probably you are correct, down vote is fine, the question read differently to me.